# Which Active Reports export type works with the HTML5 JavaScript viewer

Tags: httphandler, activereports

I have a custom Active Reports server implemented in an httphandler, which can generate and export reports in the various formats available using the AR run-time ( excel, html, PDF, ... ).  I'm now trying to use the JavaScript HTML5 viewer but it doesn't seem to be compatible with with any of the obvious export formats. The documentation and examples all show using the HTML5 viewer with the actual Active Reports server product and there are no examples for using it with a custom report service.

Client Code:

```
var viewer = GrapeCity.ActiveReports.Viewer(
{
   element: '#reportViewer',
   report: {  
      id: "report1.rdlx"
   },
   reportService: {
      url: /MyCustomReportService/reports.mrs?msg={....} 
   },
   uiType: 'desktop'

});
```

Server Code:

```
request.context.Response.ContentType = "image/gif";
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
report.Document.Save(memoryStream);
context.Response.BinaryWrite(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

also tried

```
request.context.Response.ContentType = "message/rfc822";
HtmlExport html = new HtmlExport();
html.OutputType = HtmlOutputType.DynamicHtml;
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
html.Export(report.Document, memoryStream);
request.context.Response.BinaryWrite(memoryStream.ToArray());
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you have two requirements : 
(Please refer to my forum posts for each of the below requirements)

*>>>> Using the HTML5Viewer with a CustomReportService*
http://arhelp.grapecity.com/groups/topic/rdlx-and-web-config/#post-658924
http://arhelp.grapecity.com/groups/topic/crystal-report-object-data-source-html5/#post-660665

*>>>> Implementing Custom Export in HTML5Viewer*

http://arhelp.grapecity.com/groups/topic/csv-export-from-html5-viewer/#post-658376
http://arhelp.grapecity.com/groups/topic/html5-viewer-export-to-xlsx/#post-657866
http://arhelp.grapecity.com/groups/topic/export-to-rtf-using-html5-viewer/#post-656001

Let me know if that does not works for you or you have any further issues.

Regards,
Reema